# org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid collation 'latin1_general_ci'. with MariaDB

Tags: spring, hibernate, mariadb, collation

Guys I am trying to integrated my application with MariaDb, I have created intended database and Table as per my requirement and also I have inserted demo data to test application.

As I start application I have to read some configuration values from Database to kick-off the system.

While reading data from one of the table, I am getting

```
org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter - Invalid collation 'latin1_general_ci'.
```

I also have check the collation of database and Table -

For Database -

```
SELECT @@character_set_database, @@collation_database;


+--------------------------+----------------------+
| @@character_set_database | @@collation_database |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
| utf8                     | utf8_general_ci      |
+--------------------------+----------------------+
```

For Table

```
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM USM_CONFIGURATION;

+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| Field               | Type         | Collation       | Null | Key | Default | Extra          | Privileges                      | Comment |
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
| ID                  | bigint(20)   | NULL            | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment | select,insert,update,references |         |
| ELEMENT_TYPE        | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| INTERNAL_NAME       | varchar(64)  | utf8_general_ci | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| PARENT_ID           | bigint(20)   | NULL            | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| CONFIGURATION_ORDER | int(11)      | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| HIDDEN              | smallint(6)  | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| READ_ONLY           | smallint(6)  | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| REMOVABLE           | smallint(6)  | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| ALLOW_BLANK         | smallint(6)  | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| PREFERENCE          | smallint(6)  | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| TEMPLATE            | smallint(6)  | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| DISPLAY_NAME_KEY    | varchar(64)  | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| DISPLAY_NAME        | varchar(256) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| DISPLAY_WIDTH       | int(11)      | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| DESCRIPTION_KEY     | varchar(256) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| DEFAULT_KEY         | varchar(64)  | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| DEFAULT_VALUE       | float        | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| USAGE_NOTE          | varchar(256) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| VALIDATION_CLASS    | varchar(256) | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| OWNER               | varchar(64)  | utf8_general_ci | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| UPDATE_DATE         | datetime     | NULL            | YES  |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| NS_THREAD           | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| NS_LEFT             | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| NS_RIGHT            | int(11)      | NULL            | NO   |     | NULL    |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
| VERSION             | int(11)      | NULL            | YES  |     | 0       |                | select,insert,update,references |         |
+---------------------+--------------+-----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+---------------------------------+---------+
```

In both Database and Table I couldn't see **latin1_general_ci** collation.

Why i am getting this error, is there anything which I missed while intalling DB or creating DB.

I have check with SO answers and other blogs for this error and couldn't find any specific solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.characterEncoding=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.CharSet=utf-8
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.connection.useUnicode=true
```